# Organizing the JFrame Professionally

Tags: java, swing, layout, label, panel

Looking for some help from someone who works with the Layout managers often as I normally don't use them for simpler applications etc. What I have essentially is 2 Radio Buttons with a Label beside it 'ACTIONS' following the 2 buttons 'upload', 'download' along with a jButton to the far right aligned ' Login ' What I'm having problems with is the layout manager itself every time I tweak it to try and accomplish the goal its a complete mess...   What i described about with the JRadioButtons and Button is what I desire so thats fine in the NORTH.

along with another JTextField in the SOUTH which is a message box so for example:     lines representing where WIDTH  borders would be

[Please See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r9sQ.png)

Comment: It would help if you can post the code where you are configuring the layout manager as well as a link to a screenshot (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow if you were wondering how)

Comment: Try [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) since is easy to use but powerful

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here. Also add a picture (in Paint for example) of what you want to achieve.

Comment: *apologies for the sad attempt to illustrate* maybe a paint image might be easier to understand :)

Comment: Image has been added  on my edit, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have finally got it... What needs to be done is well... a lot of tweaking there is no nice way to play with the Panels just constant tweak this center that west this North etc. very fiddly but it got the job done. I have a JAVA book that I bought way back ' Sams teach yourself Java ' seemed to have a good section highlighting BorderLayout and how to manage the certain areas (y) thanks